# What would be the extent of the feedback on climate of unattended deaths event?

Tags: climate-change, carbon-cycle, methane

Being given that decaying corpses will stop emitting digestive metane, but would release huge amount of methane during their decaying process, I was wondering if this could be considered among the [Climate change feedback loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_change_feedback)?

To illustrate this, let's just say that scenarii for year 2050 include possibility that population (and livestock) would collapse in a decade. We may have something like 200'000'000 tons mammals decaying in a 5-10 years span... This is not even a quarter on below image, but already so many methane released at once!

**Edit**: I am not looking for existing signs, I am thinking of the effect of billions of mammals death on the greenhouse effect caused by the consequent huge methane release.

[image: Land Mammals by weigth]
(copied from https://media.treehugger.com, credits XKCD)

Comment: i removed my comment i just wanted to point out that things are changing now,and it does not look good.

Comment: Thanks @trondhansen, things are not good for animals already, and my fear is that changes we see now are the very beginning riddles of numerous huge waves to come.

Comment: the main gass release after mass death of animals is CO2,large die off is not uncommon in animals like fish or livestock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mass of Earth's atmosphere: $5 \times 10^{18} kg$

Concentration of methane in Earth's atmosphere: $1866 ppb$

Mass of methane in Earth's atmosphere, present day: $9.3 \times 10^{12} kg$ = 9,300,000,000 tons

If all those dead mammals were *composed entirely of methane*, they would increase the atmospheric concentration of methane by about 2%. They aren't, and (as @trond hansen commented) most of their carbon would be converted to $\ce{CO_2}$ with a 30-fold smaller global warming footprint.

So, I think it's safe to say the impact of decomposing *mammals* would be relatively small.

Worry more about effects on *plants*, which constitute 80% of the Earth's biomass; bacteria, which constitute 15%; and fungi, which constitute about 2%. The entire animal kingdom amounts to much less than half a percent of global biomass, and half of *that* is arthropods (which have their own concerns for the future).

(Source: [figures from](https://www.pnas.org/content/115/25/6506/tab-figures-data) *The biomass distribution on Earth*, Yinon M. Bar-On, Rob Phillips, and Ron Milo, PNAS June 19, 2018 115 (25) 6506-6511; first published May 21, 2018 https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.1711842115)